# Add a ProgressDialog into a NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, progressdialog

My code does a different kinds of things, but nothing exactly like what I want.

Problem -
When the app starts, the home doesn´t show.
When an item is selected, the lateral bar `(NavigationDrawer)` is not hidden. It is not showing the next fragment until I click outside the lateral bar.

Please help :(

```js
   

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalAuthorization;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalConfiguration;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmation;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;





@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 //paypal
 public static final String TAG = "Inscripción Evento";
 public static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX;
 public static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "AU3fdxNPtXe8cz2lbvcBYt7jvJ12uA9CeYpQBNZgfHy5CvxCS6SDDGHIp7nqbBMNksrQh9u0zL3zXRnM";
 public static final int REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT = 1;
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT = 2;
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE_SHARING = 3;
    public static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration().environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT).clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID).languageOrLocale("es_MX").merchantName("iESNAJ").merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/privacy")).merchantUserAgreementUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/legal"));
 //fin paypal
 
 private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
 private ListView mDrawerList;
 private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

 // nav drawer title
 private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

 // used to store app title
 private CharSequence mTitle;
 TextView BarTitulo;

 // slide menu items
 private String[] navMenuTitles;
 private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

 private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
 private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;
 static String URL = "";
 iGuepardosVariables variables = new iGuepardosVariables();

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
  
  
     getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.iguepardos_action_bar);
  getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
  getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
  getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.space);
  //getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
  getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.header));
  getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);//agregado
  ((ActionBar) getActionBar()).setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
  
  ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this); 
   progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER); 
   progressDialog.setMessage("Loading..."); 
   progressDialog.setCancelable(false); 
  
   
  try
  {
   int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
      TextView yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
      yourTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.list_item_title));
      yourTextView.setTextSize(13);
      yourTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);//agregado
      yourTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  }
     catch (Exception e) {}

  CreaMenu();

  mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
    R.drawable.menu01, //nav menu toggle icon
    R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
    R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
  ) {
   public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
   }

   public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
    //getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
    // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
   }
  };
  mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
   // on first time display view for first nav item
   if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    if (navDrawerItems.get(0).getTitle() != null & navDrawerItems.get(1).getTitle() != null) {
     
    }
    else if (navDrawerItems.get(0).getTitle() != null) {
     
    } else {
     
    }
   }
  }
 }
 
 private void  CreaMenu()
 {
  this.VerificaPerfilLocal();
  
  mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
  mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
  mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
  
        //Declaramos el header el caul sera el layout de header.xml
        //View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
        //Establecemos header
        //mDrawerList.addHeaderView(header);
    
  // load slide menu items
  navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
     
  // nav drawer icons from resources
  navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
           
  navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

  // adding nav drawer items to array
  
  //Perfil
  if(variables.usuario.equals("")){
   navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(R.id.icon, "Usuario", "No ha iniciado sesión", null, null, 0, false));
  }
  else
  { 
   navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(R.id.icon, "Usuario", variables.usuario, null, null, 0, false));
  }
  // Home
  navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
  // Calendario de Eventos
  navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -2)));
  // Resultados
  navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
  // Contacto
  navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
  // Registra tu Evento
  navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
  // Onclick MX
  navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
  
  // Iniciar sesión
  if(variables.usuario.equals(""))
   navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
  else
   navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem("Cerrar Sesión", navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
  
  // Recycle the typed array
  navMenuIcons.recycle();

  mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener((OnItemClickListener) new SlideMenuClickListener());

  // setting the nav drawer list adapter
  adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);
  mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter); 
 }


 /**
  * Slide menu item click listener
  * */
 private class SlideMenuClickListener implements OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final int thePos = position;
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener( new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener(){

                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {

                    boolean wasChecked = !mDrawerList.isItemChecked(thePos);

                    //Toast.makeText(homeActivity, "Item pulsado: " + wasChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(thePos, !wasChecked);
                    Fragment fragment = null;
                    switch (thePos) {
                    /*case 0:
           fragment = new  HomeFragment();
           break;*/
          case 1:
           fragment = new  HomeFragment();
           break;
          case 2:
           fragment = new  CalendarioFragment();
           break;
          case 5:
           fragment = new  ContactoFragment();
           break;
          case 6:
           fragment = new  OnclickFragment();
           break;
          default:
           break;
          }

          if (fragment != null) {
           try{
           FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
           fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

           // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
           mDrawerList.setItemChecked(thePos, true);
           mDrawerList.setSelection(thePos);
           setTitle(navMenuTitles[thePos]);
           mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
           }
           catch(Exception E)
           {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
           }
          } 
          else {
           // error in creating fragment
           Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
          }
         }
            });
        }
    }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
  if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
   return true;
  }
  // Handle action bar actions click
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case R.id.action_settings:
   return true;
  default:
   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
 }

   
 /* *
  * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
  */
 @Override
 public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
  boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
  menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
  
  CreaMenu();
  
  return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
 }

 /**
  * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
  * */

 @Override
 public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
  mTitle = title;
  getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
 }

 /**
  * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
  * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
  */

 @Override
 protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
  // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
  mDrawerToggle.syncState();
 }

 @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
  mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
 }
 private void sendAuthorizationToServer(PayPalAuthorization authorization) {

        /**
         * TODO: Send the authorization response to your server, where it can
         * exchange the authorization code for OAuth access and refresh tokens.
         * 
         * Your server must then store these tokens, so that your server code
         * can execute payments for this user in the future.
         * 
         * A more complete example that includes the required app-server to
         * PayPal-server integration is available from
         * https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python/tree/master/samples/mobile_backend
         */

    }
 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == MainActivity.REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                PaymentConfirmation confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                if (confirm != null) {
                    try {
                        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));
                        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, confirm.getPayment().toJSONObject().toString(4));
                        /**
                         *  TODO: send 'confirm' (and possibly confirm.getPayment() to your server for verification
                         * or consent completion.
                         * See https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/
                         * for more details.
                         *
                         * For sample mobile backend interactions, see
                         * https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python/tree/master/samples/mobile_backend
                         */
                        
                        Fragment f = MainActivity.this.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
                  if (f instanceof EventoFragment) 
                   EventoFragment.SendEmailConfirmation(variables.direccionIpWS);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Se ha enviado un e-mail con la confirmación de la inscripción.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                        
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PaymentConfirmation info received from PayPal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(MainActivity.TAG, "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "The user canceled.");
            } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
                Log.i(MainActivity.TAG,"An invalid Payment or PayPalConfiguration was submitted. Please see the docs.");
            }
        }
 }
 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Stop service when done
  MainActivity.this.stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PayPalService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }
 private void VerificaPerfilLocal()
 {
  try
  {
   SharedPreferences preferencias;
   preferencias = getSharedPreferences("loginGuepardos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   
   if(variables.usuario.toString().equals("") && preferencias.contains("ID_EMAIL"))
   {
    variables.usuario = preferencias.getString("ID_EMAIL", null);   
   }
  }
  catch(Exception e) {}
 }
}
```

If you have an idea on what is wrong, please help me fix the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, try this, it should hide the lateral bar when you click on an item:

```
 mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.menu01, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            //getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

I'll look more deeply into your problem now.